# Wildcards - MS Word - Find replace entire line which has certain words

Tags: microsoft-word, email, regex

Saved emails from email extractor in text format.  There are many 1000s of emails with 1 email per line.  Some emails like [at]example.com and [at]mn.png must be removed from database/word file.  How to do that in word?  Can that be done in regex of email extractor itself ? Regex = ^a-zA-Z0-9-[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]

Comment: What do emails have to do with Word? Please better describe the problem.

Comment: Edited.  The emails have been saved from extractor in txt format.

Answer (score 0):

Word is not the right tool for text manipulation.

The simplest solution in Windows is the batch command
[findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html),
for example:

```
findstr /v "@example.com" file.txt >file_without_example.com.txt
```

You can also use findstr with regex, using the `/R` option. For example:

```
findstr /v /r "^@example.com$" file.txt >file_without_example.com.txt
```

But there is an endless number of other utilities that can do the job.